# Strange "If !=" Java Error

Tags: java

I am making a program that prints out if a number is prime and the prime numbers before it,  I have one problem though. I have:

```
 if(i != 2){ System.out.println(primes[i] + ", ");  else System.out.println(primes[i] +        ".");
```

If the number is 2 it should display "2." but instead it puts a period with any number ending in 3, whats wrong? :P
Here is my code

```
    package me.Jesse.PrimeCalc;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeArrayCalculator {

 public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int primeCounter = 0;
    int arrayCounter = 0;
    int[] primes;
    int input;

    System.out.println("Please Enter A Number.");
    input = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Calculating Results... (This may take a while!) ");
    System.out.println("");
    if(isPrimeMethod.isPrime(input) == true){
        System.out.println(input + " Is Prime!");
        System.out.println("Calculating The Prime Numbers Before " + input + "...");
        System.out.println("");
    }else{
        System.out.println(input + " Is Not Prime.");
        System.out.println("Calculating The Prime Numbers Before " + input + "...");
        System.out.println("");

    }



    for (int i = input; i <= input; i--){
        if(isPrimeMethod.isPrime(i) == true){
            primeCounter++;
        }
    }

    primes = new int[primeCounter++];

   for (int i = input; i <= input; i--){
       if(isPrimeMethod.isPrime(i) == true){
           primes[arrayCounter] = i;
           arrayCounter++;
       }

   }
   System.out.println("Here Are All The Prime Numbers Before " + input + ":");
   System.out.println("");
   for (int i = 0; i <= primeCounter; i++){
       try{
           if (primeCounter != 2)
               System.out.println(primes[i] + ",");
               else
               System.out.println(primes[i] + ".");
       }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
       // Yes I know the program trys to print from two invalid array index's. Try/Catch FTW.   
       }

    }
}   
    }
```

Comment: Your code snippet and your actual code are different

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what question you're asking, but what is this supposed to do?

```
for (int i = input; i <= input; i--){
        if(isPrimeMethod.isPrime(i) == true){
            primeCounter++;
        }
    }
```

what stops this looping forever?

Comment: `if(isPrimeMethod.isPrime(i))`.  Please.  `== true` just looks so ugly.  :/

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there is a lot that could be simplified in this code, but that's not the problem here.

In this case `i` is the Index of the array, not the actual value of the prime number.  Instead you should check:

```
if(primes[i] != 2)
    System.out.println(primes[i] + ", ");  
else 
    System.out.println(primes[i] + ".");
```

Comment: Thanks Htech, you answered my question, Yes... I know lots could be simplified, but I have just started learning about 1 month ago :P